# how to get image file format from QPixmap?

Tags: qt, qpixmap

In my program, user choice and load an image into `QPixmap` in some class and after some works on loaded `QPixmap` the `QPixmap` passed into an other class, in new class I want to save the passed `QPixmap` as file, but I don't know what's the `QPixmap` format!

How we can get image file format from `QPixmap`?

Comment: You can save the format as a `QString` when the image is loaded to pixmap, and pass it with the pixmap.

Comment: Since you already modified the pixmap you need to know the type. You should read on QPixmap. Eventually you could share your code so we know what you have tried and see where we can help at all. In memory pixmaps are format-neutral, so you decide which format it should be saved to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pixmap is conceptually system-specific, has no format per se, and may well lose data from the image that you've loaded. Also note that the *image format* and *file format* are two different things.

- To preserve the image format, you must use the `QImage` class.
- To preserve the file format, you must explicitly use `QImageReader` to read the image. The file format is available through the reader's `format()` method. It needs to be stored separately from the image, and used when saving the image later.
- Finally, you might wish to preserve the file's name.

As a matter of implementation detail, with the default Qt's raster backend, a `QPixmap` is a thin wrapper around `QImage`. But your intent is that of an image, not a pixmap, thus you should use the image class.

Answer (score 1):

```
QImage img = pixmap.toImage(); 
img.save("/media/mmcblk0p1/xx.jpeg");
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, and thank you for answering. While this code might answer the question, can you consider adding some explanation for what the problem was you solved, and how you solved it? This will help future readers to understand your answer better and learn from it.